# A dielectric object moves past another in an electric field. How much of its movement energy is transmitted to the second object by electric force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics

Say the objects are cubes, or square plates, and we know their permittivity, and we know the strength of the electric field they are in, and we know the moving object's mass and speed. Can we calculate how much force the moving object will apply to the other object through the medium of the electric force?

I know you can calculate the force between charges using Coulomb's law. But I don't understand what that means if neither is moving. Is the force pushing against them the whole time and holding them in place? If one charge started to move, would all of its movement energy be transmitted to the other by the electric force? Or just some of it?

Answer (score 1):

A dielectric object in an electric field polarizes; exactly what its charge
distribution is, depends on the field and the shape of the object, and forms
a second-order differential equation to be solved with boundary-value conditions
at the surface of the object, in three dimensions.

That's a nontrivial problem, and TWO objects, is another.   The polarization 
of each object adds to the field, of course.   After doing the solution,
forces between the two objects can be calculated (because you know the charge
distribution in each object).   The solutions, in general, will NOT be
simple formulae, but will have to be approximated by finite-element methods.

Such additions as 'if one charge started to move' indicate that (in addition
to electrical forces) some other forces are present.   The only general
truth here, is that dielectric objects in an E-field will generally polarize
alike, and tend to attract each other.   That is a core principle
in the theory of gasses, and leads to van der Waals attractive terms.

Comment: Thanks. I take it the electric force between the objects is constant over time? In theory, if an acceleration was applied to one object, would the same acceleration be applied to the other, via the medium of the electric force between them?

Comment: The force will change according to positions and orientations of the objects, because they contain mobile charges and may be (for instance) rotating in the external applied field.   So, the time depdence will be nontrivial if the objects are in free motion.